# Add Hidden column when exporting to CSV

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatable

This is my code :
I am using bootstrap table in php laravel. Plz Help.I dont want to show the column Accounting hidden information on my website.But when somebody click on button export it should be there in CSV file.

```
$matched.bootstrapTable({
    data: matchedData,
    height: getHeight(),
    exportTypes: ['csv', 'excel'],

    exportOptions:
    {
        fileName: 
        visible: [7,'true'],

    },    
columns: [
    {
        title: 'Booking ID',
        field: 'booking id',
        align: 'center',
        valign: 'middle',
        sortable: true,
        formatter: bookingFormatter
    }, 
{
title: 'Accounting hidden information',
    align: 'center',
    valign: 'middle',
    formatter:showAccountingNotesFormatter,
    Visible: false

},
```

Comment: Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), specifically the minimal part. From what I can tell from your post, I believe you are specifically asking for help on column visibility within the tableExport js lib. This has nothing to do with php or laravel, and the extra details cloud the issue and may be discouraging to someone who would otherwise be able to help.

Comment: @user866762 Thank you

Comment: I was mostly refering to the code itself. The `{{ $type...}}` had me confused for a second before I realized it was templating markup. You could probably hard code a value in there for the example. Also, please provide a description of exactly what is currently happening? It's not clear if the column is hidden in both the display and the export, or visible in both.

Comment: @user866762 Hello.Thanks again.i want to display column 'Accounting hidden information'.When i export this to csv.